# DotNetBrowser has hard dependency on protobuf-net version 2.4.0.0

Tags: protobuf-net

It seems there is a hard runtime dependency on protobuf-net version 2.4.0.0 despite the Nuget package declaring the dependency as >= 2.4.0.0.  I need version 3.2.30 in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Have just checked this case in an example Windows Forms project. Here is the `.csproj` file contents with all the references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <RootNamespace>WinFormsExample</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetBrowser" Version="2.24.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetBrowser.WinForms" Version="2.24.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="3.2.30" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The project ran successfully with `protobuf-net` version set to `3.2.30`, and the corresponding module version was loaded without any issue.